# Use sed to replace character with multiple conditions

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I need to replace all dot characters before equals mark, but I couldn't figure out how to go at it, as there are 2 conditions involved.

```
lib.libraries=cache,common,myjar.jar,blablabla
```

should be

```
lib_libraries=cache,common,myjar.jar,blablablam
```

Playing around for a long while on http://regexr.com/ for the right regex didn't help. It seems straightforward, but I'm quite new to regex's and I just can't crunch this one.

Edit: Forgot to mention - I also need to deal with multiple dot seperators i.e. `lib.libraries.library.etc=cache,common,myjar.jar,blablabla`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$ sed ":a;s/\.\([^=]*=\)/_\1/;ta" <<< "lib.libraries=cache,common,myjar.jar,blablabla"
lib_libraries=cache,common,myjar.jar,blablabla

$ sed ":a;s/\.\([^=]*=\)/_\1/;ta" <<< "other.lib.libraries=cache,common,myjar.jar,blablabla"
other_lib_libraries=cache,common,myjar.jar,blablabla
```

It loops over characters up to `=` and replace all `.` with `_`.

Comment: @Jahid Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
sed 's/^\(.*\)\.\(.*=.*\)$/\1_\2/g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple `awk` 1-liner:

```
$ awk -F = '{gsub(/\./, "_", $1); print $1 "=" $2}' <<< "lib.libraries=cache,common,myjar.jar,blablabla"
lib_libraries=cache,common,myjar.jar,blablabla
```

Also works for multiple dots:

```
$ awk -F = '{gsub(/\./, "_", $1); print $1 "=" $2}' <<< "lib.libraries.pkg=cache,common,myjar.jar,blablabla"
lib_libraries_pkg=cache,common,myjar.jar,blablabla
```

Answer (score 0):

This replaces the last (because of "greedy" matching) dot between the beginning of the line and the first equals sign:

```
sed 's/^\([^=]*\)\./\1_/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex: `(^(?:(?!=|\.).)*)\.((?:(?!=).)*(?=\=))`
Replace: `$1_$2`
Try this will work